# What is scope.$modelValue in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ZcA4eOttQzA

> As for knowing when ngModel's value changes, there are two ways I've
>   seen to do it. One is by overriding ngModelController's $render
>   function. Another way, which has proven more reliable in my
>   experience, is to use scope.$watch coupled with a function, as alluded
>   to above. For example:
>
> require: "ngModel", link: function link(scope, element, attrs,
>   ngModelCtrl) {   scope.$watch(function () { return scope.$modelValue;
>   }, function (value) {
>       // Do something with updated model value...   }); }

I tried this in my code but the only time it fires is at the start. Can someone explain what scope.$modelValue is exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$modelValue: The value in the model, exposed to your controller.
```

There are two views of a `ngModel` data. The `$viewValue` is the view at `DOM`. `$modelView` is what the controller has actual value of the model.

Comment: So with the following: scope.$watch(iAttrs.ngModel, function (value, oldValue) {    What's the value and oldValue? Is that similar to $viewValue and $modelValue ?

Comment: Here's what's in my HTML: <textarea ui:pagedown-bootstrap ng:model="modal.data.text"></textarea>

Comment: Yeah that's right. value is the current value in view and oldValue is the value in the model(controller part).